# How to create subcollection with uid as collection name Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection at the root of my database, userCategories.

In my app, the user can add "categories", the name of the category will be unique, and each category document looks like this:

```
{
  createdAt:Timestamp.now(),
  categoryName: userDefinedCategoryName,
  color:randomColorCode
}
```

I want the structure of this to be as follows:

```
root-
  |-userCollection
      |-uid1
      |-uid2
  |-userCategories
      |-uid1
          |-{createdAt:...,categoryName:"...",color:"..."}
           -{createdAt:...,categoryName:"...",color:"..."}
      |-uid2
          |-{createdAt:...,categoryName:"...",color:"..."}
```

I am currently using:

```
const categoryDocRef = doc(db, "userCategories", uid);
await setDoc(
  categoryDocRef, {
    createdAt:Timestamp.now(),
    categoryName:category,
    color:color
  }).then(() => {
    return {
      success: true,
      errorMessage:""
    };
  });
```

But this only allows me to create a single document within each uid, instead of multiple, as uid1 would have.

I am aware that I could do something like this:

```
const categoryDocRef = doc(db, "userCategories",uid);
const colRef = collection(categoryDocRef, "Anything Here")
await addDoc(
  colRef, {
    createdAt:Timestamp.now(),
    categoryName:category
    color:color
  }).then(() => {
    console.log(`User document for uid:${uid}`);
    return {
      success: true,
      errorMessage:""
    };
  });
```

But this creates a structure like this:

```
|-userCategories
    |-uid1
        |-anything here
            |-firebase generated id
                |-{createdAt:...,categoryName:"...",color:"..."}
                 -{createdAt:...,categoryName:"...",color:"..."}
```

I feel that the either the `firebase generated id` or the `anything here` part is unnecessary as I could use either `categoryName` or `firebase generated id` and it would avoid another layer of nesting.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Are these categories private to the user? Have you considered `/userCollection/{uid}/categories/{autoId} = {createdAt:...,categoryName:"...",color:"..."}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't possible - you can't have two documents immediately "under" a single document ID in a collection (which is uid in your case).  There can be only one document existing for each unique document ID in a collection. You also can't have a subcollection nested immediately under a collection.  A collection can only contain documents, and subcollections can only be nested under a document.

The second thing you're showing is actually a structure involving a true subcollection (which must have a name - you've named it "anything here"), and that's actually a good way to associate more than one document to a user.  It's unclear to me why you don't want that structure, but it's really the only way to go if you want to nest documents under a document with a uid for its ID.

The only other viable alternative is to not use the uid as the document ID at all, and instead:

1. Make the uid a field of the document.
2. Accept the random ID Firestore will assign to it when you add it.
3. Add as many documents as you want to the collection using the user's uid in that field.

You can then filter on that uid field to find all the documents that at associated with the user.

Comment: Okay thanks, my question now is: would it then be better to just have the "anything here" collection under the user collection? Which would have a path like this:
``/users/uid1/categories/autogeneratedID/{createdAt:...,categoryName:"...",color:"..."}``

Comment: I don't have an opinion about that.  Do whatever suits the queries you expect to perform. That's the main rule for modeling data in Firestore.